# Invoke Blackberry application with Multiple KeyPress

Tags: blackberry

I have a simple problem statement, to invoke my application when multiple key pressed in blackberry device.

For example, I have the "Capture It" application which takes screenshot with key-combinations. How do we achieve such implementations.  Any way to handle global key press event handling like how we invoke `PhoneListener` for incoming calls handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard says [in this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664283/119114), you can't implement a `KeyListener` from the background, because that would be a huge security risk.  Applications could then log your keystrokes, and steal your password.

I don't have CaptureIt, but it looks to me like it works two ways:

- first, it adds a BlackBerry menu option, to launch it.  That's completely different from allowing the app to start from **any** key combination.  That technique (adding your app into the BB menu) [is definitely supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238140/119114).
- it looks like a lot of people setup CaptureIt to run when they press their device's **Convenience Key**.  That is a special key, that you can [program to start any app on the device](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/1487/Assign_an_app_to_a_Convenience_key_29489_11.jsp), through **Options** -> **Screen / Keyboard**.

But, I don't think you can do **exactly** what you're asking.